# I'm trying to connect to an Azure service bus queue using PHP and I keep getting this error

Tags: php, azure, azureservicebus

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException' with message 'cURL error 1:
>   Protocol "sb" not supported or disabled in libcurl (see
>   http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)' in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/297R/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php:187
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/297R/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php(150):
>   GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::createRejection(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle),
>   Array) #1
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/297R/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php(103):
>   GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finishError(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler),
>   Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle),
>   Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory)) #2
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/297R/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlHandler.php(43):
>   GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finish(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler),
>   Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handle in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/297R/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php
>   on line 187

I can't find anything regarding sb protocol online and I can't do anything with this error.

Comment: How are you connecting to the service bus? Does [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-php-how-to-use-queues#set-up-a-service-bus-connection) help?

Comment: @PeterBons I'm using the exact same code on the website. it works fine until the code tries running the sendHttpContext function then i receive this error

Comment: @plank223 can you add the codes that you tried

Answer (score 4):

The Service Bus Endpoint is typically of the format `https://[yourNamespace].servicebus.windows.net`.

So, to avoid this error you need to replace the Protocol `sb` with `https`.

Reference: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-php